# Dealing with boost threads race conditions in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

I have 6 threads running in my application continuously. The scenario is:

One thread continuously gets the messages and inserts into a message queue. Other 4 threads can be considered as workers which continuously fetch messages from queue and process them. The other final thread populates the analytics information.

Problem:

Now the sleep durations for getting messages thread is 100ms. Worker threads is 200ms. When I ran this application the messages fetch thread is taking control and inserting into the queue thus increasing the heap. The worker threads are not getting chance to process the messages and deallocate them. Finally its resulting into out of memory.

How to manage this kind of scenario so that equal opportunity is given for messages fetch thread and worker thread.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: This is called [readers-writers problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readers-writers_problem). Maybe this keyword can help you with your search. Usually your writer (fetch) would check whether there is currently a reader waiting and pause. On the other hand, your readers (worker) would check whether there is a writer waiting. If you use condition variables it's very simple to achieve a basic functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a little vague so I can give you these guidelines instead of a code:

1. Protect mutual data with Mutex. In a multi-threaded [consumer producer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer-consumer_problem) problem usually there is a race condition on the mutual data (the message in your program). One thread is attempting to write on the mutual memory location while the other is trying to read from the same location. The message read by the reader might be corrupted because the writer has wrote over it in the middle of reading process. You can lock the mutual memory location with a Mutex. Each one of the threads should acquire this lock in order to be able to read or modify the mutual data. This way the consumer process will be absolutely sure that data has not been modified. However you should note that acquiring this lock might hold back the producer thread so you should release the lock as soon as possible.
2. Use condition variables to notify consumer threads. If you do not use a notification mechanisms all consumer threads should actively check for data production which will use up system resources. The consumer threads should easily go to sleep knowing that the producer thread will notify them whenever a message is ready.

The threading library in C++ 11 has everything you need to implement a consumer producer application. However if you are not able to upgrade your compiler you could use boost threading library as well.

Answer (score 4):

You need to add back-pressure to your producer thread. Usually this will done by using blocking consumer-producer queues. Producer adds items to queue, consumers dequeues items from queue and process them. If queue is empty, consumers blocks until producer adds something to queue. If queue is full producer blocks until consumers fetch items from the queue.

Answer (score 4):

One system of flow-control that I use often is to create a large pool of message objects at startup and never create any more.  The *objects are stored on a thread-safe, blocking 'pool queue' and circulated around, popped from the pool by producer/s, queued to consumer/s on other blocking queues and then pushed back onto the pool queue when 'consumed'.

This caps memory use, provides flow-control, (if the pool empties, the producer/s block on it until messages are returned from consumers), and eliminates continual new/delete/malloc/free.  The more complex and slower bounded queues are not necessary and all queues need only to be large enough to hold the, (known), maximum number of messages.

Using 'classic' blocking queues does not require any Sleep() calls.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use a bounded queue which when full will block threads trying to enqueue until more space is available.

You can use [concurrent_bounded_queue from tbb](http://threadingbuildingblocks.org/docs/help/reference/containers_overview/concurrent_bounded_queue_cls.htm), or simply use a semaphore initialized to the maximum queue size, and decrement on enqueue and increment on dequeue. boost::thread doesn't provide semaphores natively, but you can implement it using locks and condition variables.